# Is it possible to output sound to speakers over hdmi?

Tags: ubuntu, audio, hdmi

I have a sound bar (Yamaha YAS-107) which has two hdmi ports, described in the manual as follows:

```
HDMI IN jack
    For connecting an HDMI-compatible playback device such as a BD/DVD player, a satellite and cable TV tuner, and a game console (p. 22).
HDMI OUT (ARC) jack
    For connecting to an HDMI-compatible TV (p. 22).
```

I would like to listen to the music on my desktop computer through this speaker. I have tried connecting the hdmi port on my motherboard to the hdmi-in port on the speakers, but it doesn't appear among possible sound output choices.

Looking around online, there isn't much information regarding this.

Is it possible to drive speakers over hdmi?

Comment: It's usually possible. Please provide us informations about your sound card by running 'aplay -L'.

Answer (score 0):

- Connect via HDMI a Screen with Speaker(s) (e.g. TV-screen)
- Settings > Audio > Output > Output Device

Sorry for the german screenshot:
[image: Change Output device]

An english screenshot from https://linuxhint.com/per_application_sound_volume_ubuntu/ (Coypright: sreenshot below treshold of originality)
[image]